# Apply same set of functions to multiple dataframes with same column headers

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a large dataframe DF that I have split into 6 quantiles and have assigned one DF for each quantile, with each DF having the same header names.

I want to apply the same functions to all the 6 data frames and create a resultant DF that holds the results indexed by each DF.

For example generate mean, count for each column, get percentage of each variable (percentage of vlaues in each column) and so on.

These actions will be common across all DF.

As of now I do this manually as shown below

```
res_df = data.frame ("col_headers" = c("names"), 
                     "df1_out" =  c(sum(df1$C1)/nrow(df1),
                                    sum(df1$C1)/nrow(df1),...
                                    mean(df1$C1))
                      "df2_out" = c(sum(df2$C1)/nrow(df2),
                                    sum(df2$C2)/nrow(df2),...
                                    mean(df2$C1))
                        .
                        .
                        .
                       "df6_out" = c(sum(df6$C1)/nrow(df6),
                                    sum(df6$C2)/nrow(df6),...
                                    mean(df6$C1))
```

and so on. One column manually created for each variable of each data frame individually. This poses a problem for when the number of columns increase.

I was wondering if there is a way to automate this entire process of DF->Quantile split->List of DF of quantiles->mean, percentage(contribution of each row), etc->results in new DF-> comparative plots

Comment: Did you try `dplyr::mutate`

Comment: Is there a reason you're splitting into multiple dataframes, rather than using dplyr::group_by?

Comment: Yes, the reason I am splitting them is that these individual data frames need to be analyzed individually as well and also need to be compared to each other to identify differences in among them as each data frame represents a quantile (say 15% brackets) of the data.

Comment: Can you provide a sample list of data frames with `dput`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create a factor variable with the quantiles, and then use it to split() the data frame, like this (example with iris):

```
> data("iris")
> 
> iris$quantiles <- cut(iris$Sepal.Width, quantile(iris$Sepal.Width, probs = seq(0, 1, 1/6)),
+                       include.lowest = TRUE)
> lista <- split(iris, iris$quantile)
```

This will give you a list with your data frame splited into pieces. Then use lapply/sapply to perform the operations over al the data frames, like this:

```
> mediaCol <- sapply(lista, function(x) {
+   colMeans(x[colnames(x) != c("Species", "quantiles")])
+   })
> 
> mediaCol
              [2,2.7] (2.7,2.9]  (2.9,3]  (3,3.2] (3.2,3.42] (3.42,4.4]
Sepal.Length 5.757576  6.220833 6.015385 5.954167   5.550000      5.520
Sepal.Width  2.493939  2.841667 3.000000 3.154167   3.366667      3.752
Petal.Length 4.330303  4.754167 4.234615 3.770833   3.044444      2.052
Petal.Width  1.378788  1.545833 1.403846 1.254167   1.000000      0.508
```

A column percentage contribution could be:

```
> percCont <- lapply(lista, function(x) {
+   x[colnames(x) != c("Species", "quantiles")] <-
+     apply(x[colnames(x) != c("Species", "quantiles")], 2, function(y) {y / sum(y)})
+   return(x)
+ })
> 
> percCont[1]
$`[2,2.7]`
    Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width    Species quantiles
42    0.02368421  0.02794654  0.009097271 0.006593407     setosa   [2,2.7]
54    0.02894737  0.02794654  0.027991603 0.028571429 versicolor   [2,2.7]
58    0.02578947  0.02916160  0.023093072 0.021978022 versicolor   [2,2.7]
60    0.02736842  0.03280680  0.027291812 0.030769231 versicolor   [2,2.7]
61    0.02631579  0.02430134  0.024492652 0.021978022 versicolor   [2,2.7]
63    0.03157895  0.02673147  0.027991603 0.021978022 versicolor   [2,2.7]
68    0.03052632  0.03280680  0.028691393 0.021978022 versicolor   [2,2.7]
69    0.03263158  0.02673147  0.031490553 0.032967033 versicolor   [2,2.7]
70    0.02947368  0.03037667  0.027291812 0.024175824 versicolor   [2,2.7]
73    0.03315789  0.03037667  0.034289713 0.032967033 versicolor   [2,2.7]
80    0.03000000  0.03159174  0.024492652 0.021978022 versicolor   [2,2.7]
81    0.02894737  0.02916160  0.026592022 0.024175824 versicolor   [2,2.7]
82    0.02894737  0.02916160  0.025892232 0.021978022 versicolor   [2,2.7]
83    0.03052632  0.03280680  0.027291812 0.026373626 versicolor   [2,2.7]
84    0.03157895  0.03280680  0.035689293 0.035164835 versicolor   [2,2.7]
88    0.03315789  0.02794654  0.030790763 0.028571429 versicolor   [2,2.7]
90    0.02894737  0.03037667  0.027991603 0.028571429 versicolor   [2,2.7]
91    0.02894737  0.03159174  0.030790763 0.026373626 versicolor   [2,2.7]
93    0.03052632  0.03159174  0.027991603 0.026373626 versicolor   [2,2.7]
94    0.02631579  0.02794654  0.023093072 0.021978022 versicolor   [2,2.7]
95    0.02947368  0.03280680  0.029391183 0.028571429 versicolor   [2,2.7]
99    0.02684211  0.03037667  0.020993702 0.024175824 versicolor   [2,2.7]
102   0.03052632  0.03280680  0.035689293 0.041758242  virginica   [2,2.7]
107   0.02578947  0.03037667  0.031490553 0.037362637  virginica   [2,2.7]
109   0.03526316  0.03037667  0.040587824 0.039560440  virginica   [2,2.7]
112   0.03368421  0.03280680  0.037088873 0.041758242  virginica   [2,2.7]
114   0.03000000  0.03037667  0.034989503 0.043956044  virginica   [2,2.7]
119   0.04052632  0.03159174  0.048285514 0.050549451  virginica   [2,2.7]
120   0.03157895  0.02673147  0.034989503 0.032967033  virginica   [2,2.7]
124   0.03315789  0.03280680  0.034289713 0.039560440  virginica   [2,2.7]
135   0.03210526  0.03159174  0.039188244 0.030769231  virginica   [2,2.7]
143   0.03052632  0.03280680  0.035689293 0.041758242  virginica   [2,2.7]
147   0.03315789  0.03037667  0.034989503 0.041758242  virginica   [2,2.7]
```

You can reunite the data frames using unsplit():

```
> iris_percCont <- unsplit(percCont, iris$quantiles)
> 
> head(iris_percCont)
  Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width Species  quantiles
1   0.03695652  0.03731343   0.02729045 0.015748031  setosa (3.42,4.4]
2   0.03132992  0.03846154   0.01271571 0.005479452  setosa    (2.9,3]
3   0.03289013  0.04227213   0.01436464 0.006644518  setosa    (3,3.2]
4   0.03219034  0.04095112   0.01657459 0.006644518  setosa    (3,3.2]
5   0.03623188  0.03837953   0.02729045 0.015748031  setosa (3.42,4.4]
6   0.03913043  0.04157783   0.03313840 0.031496063  setosa (3.42,4.4]
```

Also, there are many ways of ploting it. The function lapply could help you with that too.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I am sorry I don't think I stated the question correctly. 
I do have the data split in quantiles. I want to apply a whole set of functions right from finding means to percentages to plotting comparative plots. I was wondering if there is a way to automate this entire process of DF->Quantile split->List of DF of quantiles->mean, percentage contribution of each row, etc->results in new DF->
comparative plot.As of now to this I do one step for each. I want to try and automate the process.
I have also edited the main question. Hope the phrasing now gives more clarity.

Comment: @sck I have edited the aswer to try to meet the extended question. Hope it serves you.

Comment: Thank you so much for the answer. It definitely helps. I am doing some version of this right now. I was getting really greedy hoping to keep the step count of the whole process really low. But this is very helpful and thank you again for answering twice!!!